# How to call NavigationDrawer.syncState() from Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I am attempting to use Kanytu's [android-material-drawer-template](https://github.com/kanytu/android-material-drawer-template) to implement a Navigation Drawer that meets Google's material design guidelines. The issue I'm facing is: Upon selecting a fragment to transition to from the navigation drawer, the selected fragment will successfully replace the current fragment within the 'container' FrameLayout. However, the HomeAsUp Indicater will display a "Back" navigation arrow in the Toolbar, rather than the Hamburger Icon needed to open the Navigation Drawer.

From what I can gather, this is due to the ActionBarDrawerToggle becoming out of sync when the fragments are being swapped. Assuming this to be the issue (I'm open for suggestions), how could I call .syncState() within the NavigationActivity fragments on the current ActionBarDrawerToggle?

```
    public class NavigationActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate( @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);
        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
        if (mToolbar != null) {
            setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_drawer);
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setup(R.id.fragment_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer), mToolbar);


        if (findViewById(R.id.container) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Menu item selected -> " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        if (position == 0) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, new UserFragment());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

           // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
            if (mToolbar != null) {
                setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.user_profile_title));
            }
        }
        if (position == 1) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, new TeamFragment());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
            if (mToolbar != null) {
                setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.team_profile_title));
            }

        }
        if (position == 2) {
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();

            // Replace whatever is in the fragment_container view with this fragment,
            // and add the transaction to the back stack so the user can navigate back
            transaction.replace(R.id.container, new ExploreFragment());
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

            // Commit the transaction
            transaction.commit();
            mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_actionbar);
            if (mToolbar != null) {
                setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(getString(R.string.explore_title));
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (mNavigationDrawerFragment.isDrawerOpen())
            mNavigationDrawerFragment.closeDrawer();
        else
            super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

---

```
    public class NavigationDrawerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<NavigationItem> mData;
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mNavigationDrawerCallbacks;
    private int mSelectedPosition;
    private int mTouchedPosition;
    private boolean isClick = false;

    public NavigationDrawerAdapter(List<NavigationItem> data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public NavigationDrawerCallbacks getNavigationDrawerCallbacks() {
        return mNavigationDrawerCallbacks;
    }

    public void setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(NavigationDrawerCallbacks navigationDrawerCallbacks) {
        mNavigationDrawerCallbacks = navigationDrawerCallbacks;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder( @NotNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.drawer_row, viewGroup, false);
        return new ViewHolder(v);
    }
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder( @NotNull NavigationDrawerAdapter.ViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.textView.setText(mData.get(i).getText());
        viewHolder.textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(mData.get(i).getDrawable(), null, null, null);
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public boolean onTouch(View v,  @NotNull MotionEvent event) {
                                                       switch (event.getAction()) {
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                                               touchPosition(i);
                                                               return false;
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                                                               touchPosition(-1);
                                                               return false;
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                                                               return false;
                                                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                                               touchPosition(-1);
                                                               return false;
                                                       }
                                                       return true;
                                                   }
                                               }
        );
        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                                   @Override
                                                   public void onClick(View v) {
                                                       if (mNavigationDrawerCallbacks != null)
                                                           mNavigationDrawerCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(i);
                                                   }
                                               }
        );
        //TODO: selected menu position, change layout accordingly
        if (mSelectedPosition == i || mTouchedPosition == i) {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(viewHolder.itemView.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.nav_selected));
        } else {
            viewHolder.itemView.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        }
    }

    private void touchPosition(int position) {
        int lastPosition = mTouchedPosition;
        mTouchedPosition = position;
        if (lastPosition >= 0)
            notifyItemChanged(lastPosition);
        if (position >= 0)
            notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
    public void selectPosition(int position) {
        int lastPosition = mSelectedPosition;
        mSelectedPosition = position;
        notifyItemChanged(lastPosition);
        notifyItemChanged(position);
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData != null ? mData.size() : 0;
    }
    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public TextView textView;
        public ViewHolder( @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_navigation_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </FrameLayout>

        <!-- android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"-->
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragment_drawer"
            android:name="com.example.appnamehere.NavigationDrawerFragment"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            app:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer"
            tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class NavigationDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements NavigationDrawerCallbacks {
    private static final String PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER = "navigation_drawer_learned";
    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_POSITION = "selected_navigation_drawer_position";
    private static final String PREFERENCES_FILE = "my_app_settings"; //TODO: change this to your file

    @Nullable
    private NavigationDrawerCallbacks mCallbacks;
    private RecyclerView mDrawerList;
    private View mFragmentContainerView;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    private boolean mUserLearnedDrawer;
    private boolean mFromSavedInstanceState;
    private int mCurrentSelectedPosition;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView( @NotNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_navigation_drawer, container, false);
        mDrawerList = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.drawerList);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        layoutManager.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        mDrawerList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        mDrawerList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        final List<NavigationItem> navigationItems = getMenu();
        NavigationDrawerAdapter adapter = new NavigationDrawerAdapter(navigationItems);
        adapter.setNavigationDrawerCallbacks(this);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);
        selectItem(mCurrentSelectedPosition);
        return view;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate( @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mUserLearnedDrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readSharedSetting(getActivity(), PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "false"));
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mCurrentSelectedPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION);
            mFromSavedInstanceState = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        try {
            mCallbacks = (NavigationDrawerCallbacks) activity;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            throw new ClassCastException("Activity must implement NavigationDrawerCallbacks.");
        }
    }
    public ActionBarDrawerToggle getActionBarDrawerToggle() {
        return mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    }
    public void setActionBarDrawerToggle(ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle) {
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = actionBarDrawerToggle;
    }
    public void setup(int fragmentId, DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
        mFragmentContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(fragmentId);
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close) {
            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if (!isAdded()) return;
                if (!mUserLearnedDrawer) {
                    mUserLearnedDrawer = true;
                    saveSharedSetting(getActivity(), PREF_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER, "true");
                }
                getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        if (!mUserLearnedDrawer && !mFromSavedInstanceState)
            mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        mDrawerLayout.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }
        });
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    }
    public void openDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    public void closeDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mCallbacks = null;
    }

    @NotNull
    public List<NavigationItem> getMenu() {
        List<NavigationItem> items = new ArrayList<NavigationItem>();
        items.add(new NavigationItem("User Profile", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_drawer_my_profile), UserFragment.class));
        items.add(new NavigationItem("Team Profile", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_drawer_my_team), TeamFragment.class));
        items.add(new NavigationItem("Explore", getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_drawer_explore), ExploreFragment.class));
        return items;
    }
    void selectItem(int position) {
        mCurrentSelectedPosition = position;
        if (mDrawerLayout != null) {
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mFragmentContainerView);
        }
        if (mCallbacks != null) {
            mCallbacks.onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(position);
        } else {
            return;
        }
        ((NavigationDrawerAdapter) mDrawerList.getAdapter()).selectPosition(position);
    }
    public boolean isDrawerOpen() {
        return mDrawerLayout != null && mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mFragmentContainerView);
    }
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState( @NotNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(STATE_SELECTED_POSITION, mCurrentSelectedPosition);
    }
    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
    public DrawerLayout getDrawerLayout() {
        return mDrawerLayout;
    }
    public void setDrawerLayout(DrawerLayout drawerLayout) {
        mDrawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    }
    public static void saveSharedSetting( @NotNull Context ctx, String settingName, String settingValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString(settingName, settingValue);
        editor.apply();
    }
    public static String readSharedSetting( @NotNull Context ctx, String settingName, String defaultValue) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = ctx.getSharedPreferences(PREFERENCES_FILE, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        return sharedPref.getString(settingName, defaultValue);
    }
```